# How to share some property between servers in a Weblogic cluster?

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

How can I reliably share a single property value between multiple servers in a Weblogic cluster -- which gets sets by one of the servers (the first one to try and access it).

Imagine it is like a static variable across the whole cluster, and the first server to access the variable gets to set it's value and that value is seen by every other server in the cluster.

I had thought the JNDI would be appropriate for this, as I read that the JNDI in a clustered environment ensures the object is shared amongst the cluster. So I set a string object in the cluster under a JNDI name and expected other servers who tried to bind the same name would get a Name Already Bound exception and thus know to use the already bound value from another server. But its not working. Each server is setting their own value in the JNDI with seemingly nothing to suggest they are accessing the same JNDI.

Comment: Have you looked at the JNDI info for binding properties and replication? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jndi/jndi.html Might be hard to help without knowing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to investigate distributed caches: http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions. They have a mechanism to have single interface for all nodes in cluster. You can learn how they do it and then implement your lightweight implementation. Or add one library to your dependencies.